# How to Setup Spinner Into Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spinner, android-adapter

I know this has been asked several times but I do not quite get it. I have an adapter and for every item, I need to set up a spinner. 
For context, I am working on a sort of product sales application. So the adapter is filled with products from the sale and the spinner has to have as many options as the product in that sale, which in my code is the quantity value.

Here is my adapter code

```java
public class MoneyDevolutionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < MoneyDevolutionAdapter.SaleDetailsViewHolder > implements View.OnClickListener {
    private List < SaleDetail > saleDetailList;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    private List < Integer > quantityList;

    public MoneyDevolutionAdapter(List < SaleDetail > saleDetailList) {
        this.saleDetailList = saleDetailList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MoneyDevolutionAdapter.SaleDetailsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_money_devolution, viewGroup, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new MoneyDevolutionAdapter.SaleDetailsViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoneyDevolutionAdapter.SaleDetailsViewHolder saleDetailsViewHolder, int i) {
        Product product = new Product().findProductById(saleDetailList.get(i).idProduct);
        if (product != null) {
            saleDetailsViewHolder.txtNameSaleDetailsAdapter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saleDetailsViewHolder.txtNameSaleDetailsAdapter.setText("" + product.nameProduct);
        }
        saleDetailsViewHolder.txtIdSaleDetailsAdapter.setText("" + saleDetailList.get(i).idProduct);
        saleDetailsViewHolder.txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter.setText("" + saleDetailList.get(i).quantity);
        saleDetailsViewHolder.txtSVSaleDetailsAdapter.setText("" + Tools.setDecimalFormat().format(saleDetailList.get(i).unitValue));
        saleDetailsViewHolder.txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter.setText("" + Tools.setDecimalFormat().format(saleDetailList.get(i).totValue));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return saleDetailList.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    static class SaleDetailsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtNameSaleDetailsAdapter;
        TextView txtIdSaleDetailsAdapter;
        TextView txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter;
        TextView txtSVSaleDetailsAdapter;
        TextView txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter;
        Spinner spnQuantityProduct;

        SaleDetailsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtNameSaleDetailsAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameSaleDetailsAdapter);
            txtIdSaleDetailsAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtIdSaleDetailsAdapter);
            txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter);
            txtSVSaleDetailsAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSVSaleDetailsAdapter);
            txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter);
            spnQuantityProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spnQuantityProducttoDevolution);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions on how to approach the making of the sppiner inside the cardview would be great, thanks!

Comment: You did not mention the issue/problem you are having.

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); Asking the right question correctly is sure to elicit more responses. It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks for the repl. I eddited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, inside the onBindViewHolder:

```
List<String> quantityArray = qArray(saleDetailList.get(i).quantity);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, quantityArray);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        saleDetailsViewHolder.spnQuantityProduct.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and then implement the qArray function

```
 private static List<String> qArray(int quantity){
        List<String> stringsArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<quantity;i++){
            stringsArray.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
        }
        return stringsArray;
    }
```